# How do I configure MySQL '5.1.49-1ubuntu8' to show multibyte characters?

Tags: mysql, query, mysql-5

I am using MySQL version 5.1.49 and I have now enabled UTF8 character encoding. The default character-set for MySQL is latin1. How can I change it show UTF8 characters?

Even when I query a table using Workbench, I get 'NULL' in the name section which I want, should display multibyte characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to consider setting the database's default character for new tables going forward using [**ALTER DATABASE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-database.html). Here is an example using MySQL 5.5.12 for Windows:

```
mysql> show create database example;
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Database | Create Database                                                    |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| example  | CREATE DATABASE `example` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */ |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter database example default character set utf8;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> show create database example;
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Database | Create Database                                                  |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| example  | CREATE DATABASE `example` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */ |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I have executed the command you suggested! But the problem is I already have data in the database Will these settings be applicable to that data too?

Comment: Only data going forward. You may haver to reload.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to specify the characterset you're using client side too.  From the mysql shell you would run

set names utf8;