# é being converted from database to site

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have a MySQL database that is storing business data... In the database, when running a select against a business name that contains an accented e (é), it comes up correctly (showing me that it is stored correctly.) On our website, though, it is showing up as the diamond with the question mark.

I checked out database and found the following:

```
Character_sets_dir          /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
Character_set_client        utf8
Character_set_connection    utf8
Character_set_database      latin1
Character_set_filesystem    binary
Character_set_results       utf8
Character_set_server        latin1
Character_set_system        utf8
```

Where things get lost is on the website itself... The web page is encoded as UTF8...

Any ideas of where the conversion may be failing?

-Wes

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask the database from another angle. Please run this:

```
SHOW CREATE DATABASE mydb;
```

This will tell you what it sees. If you want to change the Character set and.or collation, do this:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb ... ;
```

In mysql, [`ALTER DATABASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-database.html) can change character set and/or collation. I have mentioned this in my past posts in the DBA StackExchange :

- `Dec 04, 2012` : [Why default character_set_server is latin1?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29649/why-default-character-set-server-is-latin1/29818#29818)
- `Sep 18, 2012` : [change encoding of database from latin1_swedish_ci to utf8](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24453/change-encoding-of-database-from-latin1-swedish-ci-to-utf8/24454#24454)
- `Sep 26, 2011` : [How do I configure MySQL '5.1.49-1ubuntu8' to show multibyte characters?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6194/how-do-i-configure-mysql-5-1-49-1ubuntu8-to-show-multibyte-characters/6195#6195)
- `Sep 19, 2011` : [How to convert mysql database charset to utf-8](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5920/how-to-convert-mysql-database-charset-to-utf-8/5936#5936)

Comment: the result:    CREATE DATABASE `DBNAME` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */

Comment: I'm assuming that I need to set it to UTF8 then... would this have any implications to other areas of the database?

Comment: This will not change the content of the database. It may change it for new data going forward. You may need to mysqldump the data, run the `ALTER TABLE`, and reload.